# Find All Function Pointers in LLVM IR

Tags: c, function-pointers, compiler-optimization, static-analysis, llvm-ir

I want to find all occurrences of function pointers in LLVM IR and replace them with real functions. How is it possible to recognize the calls to function pointers?

Comment: How do you intend to resolve the call target?

Comment: Two heuristic-based approaches at the high level source code level: 1) Check for all assignments to a function pointer and 2) check for all struct initializations (the code is in C) that contains a function pointer.

Comment: fair enough, you can insert your heuristic logic in the innermost if condition I have created in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a [FunctionPass](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1FunctionPass.html).

In the `runOnFunction` function, you can iterate over all the instructions and check if any of them are Indirect Function calls as -

```
for (Function::iterator BB = F.begin(); BB != F.end(); BB++) {
    BasicBlock &bb = *BB;
    for (BasicBlock::iterator I = bb.begin(); I != bb.end(); I++) {
        if (CallInst *CI = dyn_cast<CallInst>(I)) { // Check if call instruction 
            if(CI->getCalledFunction() == NULL) { // Check if call instruction is indirect
                //replace CI with new instruction 
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

The [`getCalledFunction`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1CallBase.html#ae001f2763f387fe3e9a24319f53263aa) member function returns `NULL` if the call is indirect.

Comment: Does it recognize macros?

Comment: Macros? I don't think I understand you clearly. Can you provide an example?

Comment: An example from MPlayer-1.3.0 source code: `#define cache_stream_fill_buffer(x) stream_fill_buffer(x)`. Somewhere in the code we can have `if (!cache_stream_fill_buffer(...))...`.

Comment: @TheAhmad when you convert source code to LLVM IR, all macros have been expanded by the preprocessor.

Comment: The compiler doesn't see macros. The preprocessor performs the substitution. So it doesn't matter how the indirect call was made, this will iterate over it.

Comment: How about this case:  `%49 = tail call i32 bitcast (i32 (%struct.stream.3110*)* @cache_stream_fill_buffer to i32 (%struct.stream*)*)(%struct.stream* nonnull %1) #6, !dbg !847613`
The call is not a call to a function pointer but `getCalledFunction` returns `NULL`.

Comment: As @firefroge mentioned here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653072/how-can-i-get-function-name-of-indirect-call-from-callinst-in-llvm, the function name can be accessed after pointer casts are stripped while no name is in hand in the case of function pointers. This helps to distinguish between function pointers and pointer casts of real functions.

Comment: I also used `CI->isInlineAsm()` to distinguish between inline assembly and a call to a function pointer.

Comment: Can you identify function pointers from the argument list of a function? Like iterating over the arguments and performing some kind of checks on them?