# How to detect function pointers from assignment statements in LLVM IR?

Tags: function, llvm, llvm-ir

I want to detect all occurences of function pointers, calls as well as assignments. I am able to detect indirect calls but how to do the assignment ones? Is there a char Iterator in the Instruction.h header or something which iterates character by character for each instruction in the `.ll` file?
Any help or links will be appreciated.

Comment: This seems quite simple, but underspecified: As if you haven't tried, but when you try you'll find that the problem is simple. I suggest that you look at the IR for some relevant function, find out which instructions you want to detect and then think about how to detect them. The iterators you want are in [BasicBlock](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1BasicBlock.html) and Function, BTW.

Comment: I already read through the Doxygen docs a couple of time... basicblocks, function, instructions couldn't really figure out what is the missing piece function/iterator i need. :(

Comment: The function or block itself. Given a `Function&f`, you can do `for(auto &b : f) { for(auto &i : b) {…` to iterate over the instructions in the blocks in the function. You can find many similar examples in the LLVM source, try `grep 'for.*Instr' llvm/IR/*.cpp`. Generally grepping for any type in the LLVM source finds examples of its use, and one of the first ten usages will be an illustrative example.

Comment: Yes I did that for detecting indirect calls as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50761292/find-all-function-pointers-in-llvm-ir ... I just got no idea how do you find the assignment statements involving function pointers like `void (*func)() = function;` :(

Comment: You do it by looking at some relevant generated IR and finding out which **IR constructs** you want to detect. Once you've found out which generated IR you want to detect, the rest is probably simple: The IR language is specifically designed for such tasks. It is not designed for solving problems that you've only described in terms of a different language.

Comment: Any more last hints? Like Which header documentation should i narrow my search to now? Its a mess in the official docs, too much stuff to read and make sense.

Comment: I mean there's a lot of stuff to read and figure out which ones gonna be relevant to my needs. So if someone could help and narrow down my search it would be helpful.

Comment: LLVM IR does not have an assignment statement. The closest it has is `store` instruction which writes to memory.

Comment: @NickLewycky Who said it has?

Comment: @Tony, the remark was intended to be informative. "How to detect function pointers from assignment statements in LLVM IR?" C's assignment states are converted into `store`s then mostly deleted while LLVM doesn't have assignment statements to detect. For what it's worth my common advice for trying to find a property of the source language is to do it in a parser of that languages and not in LLVM IR.

Comment: @NickLewycky Maybe ur right i am very new to LLVM and compilers. My proff has given a bunch of students this assignment of finding occurrences of function pointers in C(by writing a Pass). Be it indirect calls or assignments. He also told to extract the name of the function being referenced through the pointer and from what I have read, is just considered impossible. (Because the getCalledFunction function returns NULL so you would have to do other funky stuff.) At this point (after painstakingly reading through the docs and being able to detect indirect calls) I am completely clueless.

Answer (score 1):

Start with unoptimized LLVM IR, then scan the use-list for all functions.

In the comments we established that this is for a school project, not a production system. The difference when building a production system is that you should rely only on the properties that are guaranteed, while for research or prototyping or schoolwork, you can build something that happens to work by relying on properties that are not guaranteed. That's what we're going to do here.

It so happens (but is not guaranteed!) that as clang converts C to LLVM IR, it will[1] emit a store for every function pointer used. As long as we don't run the LLVM optimizer, they will still be there.

The "forwards" direction would be to look into instructions and see whether any of them do the action you want (assign or call a function pointer). I've got a better idea: let's do it backwards. Every `llvm::Value` has a list of all places where that value is used, called the use-list. For example `%X = add i32 %Y, %Z`, %X would appear in the use-list of %Y because %X is using %Y.

Starting with your Module, iterate over every function (ie. `for (auto &F : M->functions()) {`), then scan the use-list for the function (ie. `for (const auto *U : F.users())`) and look at those Values (ie. `U.get()`). If the user value is an Instruction, you can query which Function this Instruction belongs to -- the Instruction has a parent BasicBlock and the BasicBlock has a parent Function. If it's a ConstantExpr, you'll need to recurse through that ConstantExpr's use-list until you find all the instructions using those constants. If the instruction is a direct call, you want to skip it (*unless* it's a direct call with an argument that is also a function pointer, like `somefun(1, &somefun, 2);`).

This will miss any code that uses C typed function pointers but never point to any functions, for instance C code like `void (*fun_ptr)(int) = NULL;`. If this is important to you then I suggest writing a Clang AST tool with the RecursiveASTVisitor instead of using LLVM.

[1] clang is free not to, for instance given `if (0) { /* ... */ }` clang could skip emitting LLVM IR for the disabled code because it's faster to do that. If your function pointer use was in there, LLVM would never get the opportunity to see it.