# Is there any way to get function-name of indirect call from CallInst in LLVM IR

Tags: llvm

I am working on a problem to extract the function name of indirect call from CallInst in LLVM IR. Is there any way to get function-name of indirect call?  Basically, I need to find all called functions including ones called through function pointer.

C Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void (*fun_ptr)(int);

void fun(int a)
{
     printf("Value of a: %d\n", a);
}

int func_3(int a, int b)
{
    (*fun_ptr)(a+b);
}

int main ()
{
    fun_ptr = fun;
    func_3(4, 5);
}
```

LLVM IR:

```
 30   %retval = alloca i32, align 4
 31   %a.addr = alloca i32, align 4
 32   %b.addr = alloca i32, align 4
 33   store i32 %a, i32* %a.addr, align 4
 34   store i32 %b, i32* %b.addr, align 4
 35   %3 = load void (i32)*, void (i32)** @fun_ptr, align 8 ;Can we retrieve the value of @fun_ptr
 36   %4 = load i32, i32* %a.addr, align 4
 37   %5 = load i32, i32* %b.addr, align 4
 38   %add = add nsw i32 %4, %5
 39   call void %3(i32 %add) ;Indirect Call
 40   %6 = load i32, i32* %retval, align 4
 41   ret i32 %6
```

LLVM PASS:

```
for(Function::iterator BB = F.begin(), E = F.end(); BB != E; ++BB)
{
    for(BasicBlock::iterator BI = BB->begin(), BE = BB->end(); BI != BE; ++BI){
        if (CallInst *CI = dyn_cast<CallInst>(BI)) {
          CF = CI->getCalledFunction();
          if (CF) {
            // Direct function call
            std::string fName = CF->getName().str(); //Name of callsite function
          } else {
            //Indirect function call (Via Function pointer)
            //Can we get the function name? or Get the address of function pointer and resolve it using symbol table offline?
          }
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to find the function name of direct call and detect the indirect function call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get Function Name of indirect call from CallInst in LLVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653072/how-can-i-get-function-name-of-indirect-call-from-callinst-in-llvm)

Answer (score 2):

No.

Depending on what produced the LLVM IR, you might be lucky and have the `!callees` metadata that tells you the set of possible called functions from a call site. https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#callees-metadata

You can eliminate some functions, if you can prove their address isn't taken, or if you analyze how it's taken and show that the function address couldn't possibly flow into this call site through some complex custom interprocedural data flow analysis.

Further, if you consider "calling the function would be undefined behaviour" to be the same as not calling the function, then you can limit the possible set of callees to the ones which don't have an ABI mismatch.

When doing this, consider that you can dlopen() and dlsym() most programs and use their functions directly without going through their main(). For that matter, is the object file being compiled the main program or is it part of a shared object? And what if the user is using ELF symbol interposition (replacing a function in your program with another one)? Or a JIT? Any function whose linkage allows access from another object file should be considered "address taken and spread to everybody" or else I could craft a program and situation that your analysis would be incorrect for.

In general, there is no way to know.

Comment: I would add that indirect function calls tend to be used precisely because the name of the function isn't known. If the compiler or programmer knows, then the instruction call tends to be a direct function call. Indirect calls are used when not.

Comment: There may not be any function name at all. You can malloc(), write in native machine code as bytes into it, then call it.

Comment: @NickLewycky Thank you Nick for your quick reply and detailed explanation.